# is there something wrong in js.ejs?

Tags: javascript, express

why get error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in my console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78T6n.png)
[code full:] https://github.com/Mustofaadni04040/bwamern-backend.git

I cannot figure out how to solve this issue and is there is something wrong with file structure or i made mistake while referencing the file name

app.js:

```
app.js: app.use(
  "/sb-admin-2",
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2"))
);
```

js.ejs:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="/sb-admin-2/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/sb-admin-2/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="/sb-admin-2/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script src="/sb-admin-2/js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Page level plugins -->
    <script src="/sb-admin-2/vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/sb-admin-2/vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Page level custom scripts -->
    <script src="/sb-admin-2/js/demo/datatables-demo.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I've just forked your repo, I get `200 OK` where you have all that 404 errors.

Comment: As already suggested, include code/errors in plain text

Comment: solved thanks bro, apprently because sb-admin-2 must be updated